# The value can't pass in Constructor JAVA

Tags: java, constructor

I need the value of num in my constructor why is is that the value of num in the constructor became Zero even though i use set and get just to put the value 9000 here. Thank you in advance :)

this is my First Class

```
public class NewClass1 {

private int num;

   public NewClass1() {
   System.out.println("Get Num: "+num);
   }

    public void setNum(int n) {
       num = n;
   }

   public int getNum() {
      return num;
   }
   public void Message() {
       System.out.println(num);
   }

    }
```

this is my main class

```
public class NewClass2 {

public static void main(String[] args ) {
NewClass1 obj = new NewClass1();
obj.setNum(9000);
obj.Message();
}}


Output: GetNum: 0
        9000
```

Comment: You are definitely not a java developer.

Comment: Im just a student -.-

Comment: thanks jatin :) ahmmm it should be num = n; Thank you for your answers, there is no error now :)

Comment: Please study how an object is constructed and how the constructor getting invoked. You will get the answer. When you create an object the constructor will get called and that print statement with default integer value 0 will get printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have to pass your value inside constructor.

public class NewClass1 {

```
private int num;

public NewClass1( int n)
{

    n=num;
    System.out.println("Get Num: "+num);

}
   public int getNum() {
      return num;
   }

   public void Message() {
       System.out.println(num);
   }

    }

 and your main class will look like this

public class NewClass2
 {

    public static void main(String[] args ) {
    NewClass1 obj = new NewClass1(9000);// your valur
    obj.Message();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a constructor that takes an int parameter, just like your setter method.

e.g.,

```
public class Foo {
  private int bar;

  public Foo(int bar) {
     this.bar = bar;
  }

  // .... more code, getters, setters, toString,...
}
```

And you'll want to remove the System.out.println's from your NewClass1 class. Those should be in the classes that use NewClass1.

```
class TestFoo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Foo foo = new Foo(42);
     System.out.println("bar is: " + foo.getBar());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another constructor that takes a int parameter, and use this one to set the private member. Here's how :

```
public NewClass1(int n)
{
    num=n;
}
```